# Is the use of 'trade off' wrong in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> Plenty of evidence has shown that human beings actually have to sacrifice some benefits of the other creatures on the earth for **trading off** the development of human beings, which in turn proves that other creatures on the earth are regarded as fuel for the wheels of human beings' evolvement. (This is talking about animal testing.)

I did look up 'trade off' in the dictionary, but I didn't see any examples that use the phrase as it is in the above sentence. So did the author use it wrongly? Thank you!

Comment: "Trading off" is incorrect, and there are several other errors as well. Where did you find this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is from a sample essay for an English test. I feel 'fuel for the wheels' is a bit strange as well, never seen that before, since you said 'several errors', it is probably wrong too.

Comment: You clearly know more English than the writer of the sample! --also, "benefits", which appears to represent something like "welfare",   "evolvement" for "evolution", and the odd repetition of "human beings". But it's hard to know where this is inadequate English and where it's hasty or uneducated thought.

Comment: Was it supposed to be a *model* sample essay? Or was part of an exercise to find mistakes?

Comment: Hi Stoney, thanks for pointing out the errors! I can feel it is not well written but not sure where and how to correct it, your comment is really helpful.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the comment. What is the difference between 'sample essay' and 'model sample essay'? I paid for those essays to get ideas for writing, some of them are quite good, some of them are terrible, most of them have errors. I bought them because it is really hard to come up all the ideas for all the topics on my own. It's not a finding error practice.

Comment: I see. Yes, at first I understood "sample essay" as an essay to model, a good example of essay writing. I think this is usually what a "sample" something is supposed to be. However, sometimes sample things are actually problems or exercises. For example, professors often give _sample exams_ like a sample final. This is used for practice for the real final exam. Since ELL users are often taking English _classes_, I thought that this might have been a _sample exam problem_, for example, where you are expected to notice the errors and attempt to correct them.

Comment: Also, to address/ping a user who has made a comment, use the @ symbol. Unless you are commenting under that person's post. Then to reach that person, you do not need the @.

Comment: @Max might be worth explaining why ... until recently I had thought this was more decoration or convention than of functional value.

Comment: @Max Will do :) It suppose to be a model but some of the essays are poor quality :(

Comment: I think what djna means is that I should say that if you do not use the @, then the other user will not receive a notice (the little red square with the number in the center). Anyway, I think you get how to use it now :) About the essays, I would say try to find a different service because model/sample essays are supposed to be high quality, without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text is riddled with errors. Do not use it as a basis for your own work.

You're right that **trading-off** is not used correctly. We should explicitly say **trading-off A for B** not **A for trading-off B**

Also, as you spotted, **fuel the wheels** is a mixed metaphor. We fuel fires or engines, or possibly growth, we turn wheels.

The phrase **sacrifice some benefits of the other creatures of the earth** is also very odd. I'm not sure of the author's intent here. In context I think he is trying to say that we do things that do not **benefit** other creatures, but as written we are sacrificing something that the creatures give us, sacrificing their benefits to us.

**evolvement** is a very rarely used noun. I would expect many English speakers to think it was an error, I had to look it up. But anyway it is not evolution we are talking about, advancement or development perhaps.